# Appending content upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a reference error every time I try to run this fiddle.

The function is supposed to add another radio button to form.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/RyeManship/2jtvjd28/

HTML

```
    <section class="content">
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here">
  </label>
</div>
</section>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:AddQuestion()">Add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Submit Question</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function AddQuestion() {
$(".content").append('<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here"></label></div>');
};
```

Comment: Hello, just change in the javascript options -> load type -> set "no wrap in body" (or no wrap in head): https://jsfiddle.net/2jtvjd28/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2jtvjd28/3/ you've just to add the code to the `<head>` instead of `Load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your fiddle is setup incorrectly. When using an `on*` event attribute the function has to be within scope of the `window`, so you need to change 'Load Type' in the JS settings from `onLoad` to `No Wrap - in <head>`.

[**Fixed fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2jtvjd28/1/)

Note that a much better solution entirely would be to not use any outdated event attributes at all and replace them with unobtrusive event handlers. This leads to a much better separation of concerns as the HTML and JS are now completely disconnected. As you're already using jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $(".content").append('<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here"></label></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here">
    </label>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add">Add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Submit Question</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I have updated my fiddle, however the remove function does not work but no errors are occurring in the console. Any suggestions? https://jsfiddle.net/RyeManship/2jtvjd28/5/

Comment: Three problems there. You need to put your code in a document.ready handler. `this` refers to the clicked button and none of the rows are the `parent()` of that button. `.content` is not the parent of the button, so you need to use `.row` as the delegated event handler. Assuming you want to remove the last added row, use this: https://jsfiddle.net/2jtvjd28/6/